# What happened to The Others storyline?

Tags: earth-final-conflict

In S04E16 of *Earth: Final Conflict*, *Trapped by Time*, 3 astronauts from the future are discovered to have been recovered by the US government decades ago.  During the episode, one astronaut is revived.  He reveals that humans and the Others got rid of the Taelons long ago.  The Others being some new race that humanity found.

Then in the 4th season finale, the last Taelons (and Jaridians) go into the rejuvenation pods, and emerge in the 5th season as Atavuses.  This doesn't jive with what the astronaut foreshadowed.

What happened to the storyline involving The Others that seemingly got dropped?  Were any details about it ever revealed to the public?

Comment: The show ended at the conclusion of season 4. However, the producers wanted to milk it for another few episodes... and the half-assed season 5 was done. I don't think it can be considered canon without ruining the stories of season 1 through 4. There's just no way to reconcile 5 with the rest. There is a prequel novel written by Saberhagen which, while probably not canon (and certainly not inspired) was quite readable (it was F. Saberhagen after all). I know of no such novelizations other than that.

Comment: A perfect example of this; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PostScriptSeason